# ASP.NET HttpContext.RewritePath creates new thread

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, httpmodule

After update Framework on server from 4.0 to 4.5, RewritePath started to work differently.
It used to handle request at the same thread, but now it always create new one (checked by logs MangedThreadId).
I couldn't find any mention about that in 4.5 ASP.NET features list.
Any thoughts ?

**EDIT:**
It's been used to get parameter from ulr, i.e host/param/Handler.ashx, and set it to context which is static thread.

Comment: Interesting observation. Why does it matter?

Comment: @nunespascal, my guess is that perhaps OP is using thread context/storage to pass some info along. `HttpContext` would be better alternative as ideally ASP.NET should marshal it on thread switch.

Comment: @VinayC, I want to elicit the exact use-case from the OP, so as to suggest a better approach than depending on the same thread.